# Regarding Enable & Diasable of Dual Boot Option?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, customization, privacy

I'm using Dual Boot hence while booting I'm supposed to click an option as shown below (Ex:)

[image: Dual Boot]

So, Tell me how to disable the options of dual boot i.e system should boot directly without options as shown below

[image]

And also I should be able to Enable it again as shown in the First Picture.

Gimme the possible ways to achieve it **without affecting**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favorite text editor (I'm using `nano` here):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that says:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=<some number here, eg: 10>
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
```

This will show the menu, but for just a second and after that it will boot the default entry. If it is set to `0`, still you will see it for 10 seconds as a security measure. So put `1` there.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes to your file and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to Exit. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Hint: Take a copy of your Grub before editing**

Comment: did you use `nano'? If yes, hit Ctrl+O, hit enter and then hit Ctrl+X

Comment: It is as I said above. Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. it will ask for your root password. Enter password and you should be inside nano. Find the line you want to edit (in my file it is the 9th line, might be different for you), change the timeout value to 1, hit Ctrl+O, confirm by pressing Enter, then to exit press Ctrl+X

Comment: Yes i did it, It works for me. Thanks a lot @ron

Comment: To take a copy: `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_backup` which we will be helpful i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right .. 
Edit /etc/default/grub

***Editing my answer***

set these options below

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Remember to run `update-grub`

If you need to get the grub menu on boot for whatever reason hold shift down while booting your pc.

Comment: No, if you put `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` it will still display the boot menu for 10 seconds.

Comment: I think your right..  how about adding this to GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true